# Propogation of waves across many worlds

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

If we accept the Many Worlds Interpretation literally, is it not possible there is propagation of waves directly between worlds? For example, given that ‘every eventuality exists’ in MWI, there should, amongst others, be infinities of only-minutely-different worlds in superposition. We can imagine one infinite set of worlds such that each has basically the ‘same wave’ passing across it but when superimposed the waves in each world are infinitesimally out of phase and spatially separated. (Planck amounts). Could we not suppose this would allow a kind of diagonal propagation across worlds? (We imagine them stacked and lined up next to each other -slightly staggered to infinity) Would we be able to test for this, if the waves crossing worlds are ubiquitous? I imagine with uncountable infinities of these sets of worlds, the crossing waves would head in all directions.. 
if this isn’t the case, why not - given some people accept waves interfere across many worlds?

Comment: https://phys.org/news/2014-10-interacting-worlds-theory-scientists-interaction.html

Comment: THanks [lurscher] I looked into MIW too hoping it described a similar system but couldn’t exactly get to the bottom of what they were saying about interaction...

Comment: Obviously, if this is possible, it would mean lateral causality across worlds. Time would unfold, for the crossing waves, in the direction of flight, orthogonal to ‘our time’, crossing us in what we call spatial dimensions, without progress forward in our time. Is this why entangled particles appear to communicate instantly? What do you think? Is this possible - or not?

Comment: If we had "lateral causality across worlds," how could we ever invoke causality within our own world? The concept would possibly never have been imagined.

Comment: We might imagine that  routes of causality engaged imperceptibly. The same particles have double (or more) ‘usage’ in different directions. To take a macroscopic example 2 perpendicular  solitons passing through each other, unaffected. In essence becoming one momentarily as they cross.